# Webpack: Load a file that does not (yet) exist in the filesystem

Tags: json, webpack

I would like to add JSON files from a remote location into my Webpack bundle. To do so, I am writing a loader, which will pull the files from their remote location into the bundle.

I am getting an error while trying to do so. Is there a way to supercede the "file not found" error to try and resolve a module against whatever loaders it matches regardless of it's existence?

Here is the error:

```
 *:81
            throw stats.compilation.errors[0];
                                          ^
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../../json/test.json in *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this via loaders -- loaders are applied to the source once webpack has it; if there's no source it can't apply a loader. If you really want to dig into it, check out `NormalModuleMixin.js` (it's in `webpack-core/lib`, which is in `webpack/node-modules`).

If you really want to make webpack treat that resource as a local file, you could write a custom resolver plugin, which would identify `require` calls for the remote resource, download it, and then let the `require` resolution continue once the file exists locally. Writing custom resolvers is unfortunately more-or-less undocumented. [Here's an issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/110) where @sokra points out some references; I found [this plugin](https://github.com/webpack/component-webpack-plugin/blob/master/index.js) in particular to be a good example of how it works.

The easiest way to do what you're shooting for might be to have Grunt/Gulp/a shell script pull the file down before executing the webpack build.

Comment: This is as close to an answer to this question as I think exists. I ended up combining a plugin and a loader.